# Lock happens when I execute stored procedure inside trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, table-lock

I have a trigger for executing two procedures.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_SP_SYNCH_CAB]
   ON [VTBO_INTERFACE].[dbo].[T_TRIGGER_TABLE_FOR_SYNCH]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    INSERT INTO T_TRIGGER_TABLE_FOR_SYNCH (DT) 
    VALUES (GETDATE());

    exec PUMPOMAT_HO.DBO.SP_CM_TransferCAB
    exec PUMPOMAT_HO.DBO.SP_CM_UpdateCAB

END
```

Execution time for two procedures is 5 mins. When I try to insert a value to T_TRIGGER_TABLE_FOR_SYNCH table, my other tables which are used in stored procedures are locked along 5 mins. But when I try to execute two procedures directly like

```
exec SP_CM_TransferCAB
exec SP_CM_UpdateCAB
```

No lock happens. What should I write in trigger to avoid of table locks.

Thanks.

Comment: *"Execution time for two procedures is 5 mins"* - Then these two procedures do not belong in a trigger!! I would start by addressing why you need to execute 5 minute long procedures for every insert before you address the issue of locking.

Comment: I need to execute the sql server stored procedure inside an oracle procedure. There is a dblink between two servers. I am not able to execute sp directly, but I am able to insert a record. That is an alternative way for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by calling the second procedure inside(end of) the first procedure since I see no parameters are given.

Is this table `[VTBO_INTERFACE].[dbo].[T_TRIGGER_TABLE_FOR_SYNCH]` used in any of the procedure?

You should try to `change the design/data flow to mimic this procedure call`.

Comment: Even if I use only one procedure in trigger, the lock still happens. For example the lock takes 3 mins if I use only the first procedure.